# Looking for paper: The Cauchy integral by M. Privalov

Tags: reference-request, journals

I am looking for a paper titled *The Cauchy integral* by M. Privalov (Saratov, 1919).

The paper is written in Russian. It is being cited (for instance) by A. Kolmogorov in the paper *Sur les fonctions harmoniques conjuguées et les séries de Fourier* (Fundamentals Math. **7**, pp. 23-28 (1925)), which is written in French. Kolmogorov cites it as 'M. Privaloff - L'intégral de Cauchy, Saratoff (1919)'.

Unfortunately, I don't know much Russian, so it is not possible for me to use any Russian website where Privalov's paper might be available. I have been searching for it, but apart from other citations there seems to be no information as to how one could access it via internet.

Does *Saratov* even mean an actual journal here, or is it just the author being a member of the Saratov State University?

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint. Thanks in advance and apologies for the possibly naive question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This book can be found on the internet using the right search terms: Привалов, интеграл Kоши (= Privalov, integral Cauchy). This quickly leads you to the book (it's not an article) at http://bookre.org/reader?file=729538 and press the button marked >| to advance a page or use the page drop-down button to go immediately to a specific page.

The table of contents is at the end (typical of Russian books), starting on p. 99 and going for one additional page than is available from the drop down page number bar (so use the >| button to see it). Press the button near the top of the page labeled Скачать to download a .djvu version of the book.

Update (2021):  This answer was upvoted recently, which drew my attention to it again, and I noticed that my link above appears to be broken: it does not work in two browsers that I tried. Here is another link to the book, at archive.org: https://archive.org/details/libgen_00292731. I hope this one will be more robust over time.

Privalov was a professor at Saratov University (it says this at the top of the front cover), but I think writing "Saratov, 1919" means nothing other than that this is the city where the book was published.

Comment: Here is another link that should work, as a backup in case of trouble with one of the links above: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uv2JJVcUcJrpFKIUKNJI8s7RDFy6s-Gp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 9):

Here is another place
http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=141444
It is in djview format (the djview reader is available for free, 
it is an improved version of pdf).
This cite contains most of the existing math books in Russian.

A paper version of the book is an extreme rarity. It was published during Russian Civil war
in a provincial Russian city. I have never seen a paper copy in my life. It
is believed that most of this book was incorporated in his later book
Boundary properties of analytic functions, Moscow 1950 which was printed in
many copies, and was more available. Unfortunately this second book is also available
only in Russian.

Comment: the link on the website does not seem to work (for me).

Comment: Loic Teyssier: reload once or twice, and click on the book cover. You need to install a djview reader too.It works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a translation into German, "Randeigenschaften analytischer Funktionen", VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften, Berlin (East) 1956.

Comment: This is a translation of his 1950 book, not of the earlier 1919 version that is asked.